# How to smoothly change the target of smooth follow without camera glitch?

Tags: unity, camera, lerp

I am trying to change the target of the smooth follow at runtime, but there is a glitch in the camera since the targets are different sizes. I tried using lerp and smooth damp both gave the same result. How do I overcome the jerk in camera motion?

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of it the error is probably not due to the size of the targets (as that would not modify their position, only their volume). Try using a larger time scale with smoothdamp, perhaps only used during a change over period between targets.

Another option would be to use slerp instead during the switch over; to get the slower acceleration. Without seeing your actual code, it is difficult to see the exact problems (and unfortunately I am not in front of my development machine at this precise time).

Side note: What you MAY want to program in is a "springy-ness" factor into the camera tracking code. I'd look into implementing this, and that code would probably solve your problem (as this sounds like a "camera snap" issue, rather than a "glitch" per say).